# WPF with SciChart in the separate AppDomain

Tags: c#, wpf, appdomain, scichart

I'm trying to run my WPF with SciChart aplication in the separate AppDomain, but method SciChartSurface.SetRuntimeLicenseKey() is not working for me - no any exception, but in SciChart control I can see "Sorry! Your trial of SciChart has expired. Please contact sales if you require an extension." instead of Chart.

In the default AppDomain it works fine.

I tried to run SetRuntimeLicenseKey method from both AppDomains - Default and separate, but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used SciChart's [WPF Chart](http://scichart.com/wpf-chart-features) in an application with multiple AppDomains so I know it works.

What is necessary to do is to call the [SetRuntimeLicenseKey() once and once only](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/Licensing.html) (per AppDomain), before any SciChartSurface instance is called. This way the licensing is initialized before a SciChartSurface is shown.

> [(From SciChart Documentation)](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/Licensing.html)
>
> *To apply the runtime key, you need to call
>   SciChartSurface.SetRuntimeLicenseKey() once before any SciChartSurface
>   is instantiated. A good place to do this is in App.xaml.cs*

There is a [Licensing Troubleshooting page for SciChart WPF here](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-licensing-troubleshooting). I suggest if you experience problems to follow these steps and contact their technical support, who will be able to help you.